# DataSet javaRDD() performance

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting retrieving data from `Cassandra`in a `Spark`Application using `Spark SQL`. Data is retrieved as `DataSet`. However, I need to convert this `dataset`to `JavaRDD` using `javaRDD()` function. It works, however it takes about 2 hours. Is there some parameters to adjust to enhance this time?

Answer (score 3):

`Dataset APIs` are built on top of the `SparkSQL` engine, it uses `Catalyst`to generate an optimized logical and physical query plan. Across `R, Java, Scala,` or `Python DataFrame/Dataset APIs`, all relation type queries undergo the same code optimizer, providing the space and speed efficiency. Whereas the `Dataset[T]` typed API is optimized for data engineering tasks, the `untyped Dataset[Row]`(an alias of `DataFrame`) is even faster and suitable for interactive analysis.

For more details [Spark RDD vs Dataset performance](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html)

[image]

Comment: Nitpick... Dataset[Row] is not faster than Dataset[T] because the typed Dataset has an explicit encoder. If the problem needing a solution is an iterative approach, unfortunately RDDs are the best approach. Most SparkML algorithms use RDDs under the covers despite exposing Dataset APIs because ML problems are often iterative and Catalyst is not good at optimizing iterative problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Resilient Distributed Dataset (RDD)** is the main abstraction of Spark framework while Spark SQL (a Spark module for structured data processing) provides Spark more information about the structure of both the data and the computation being performed, and therefore uses this extra information to perform extra optimizations.

Up until Spark 1.6, RDDs used to perform better than its Spark SQL counterpart DataFrame (https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42027/rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-sparksql.html), however, Spark 2.1 upgrades have made Spark SQL quite more efficient

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmhXf.png